# what is "script name symbol" means for emacs set-fontset-font function?

Tags: emacs, configuration, fonts, elisp, emacs23

When I read the documentation about `set-fontset-font`, I found there is a sentence like below:

> (set-fontset-font NAME TARGET FONT-SPEC &optional FRAME ADD)
>
> Modify fontset NAME to use FONT-SPEC for TARGET characters.
>   ...
>   TARGET may be a ***script name symbol***.  In that case, use FONT-SPEC for all characters that belong to the script.
>   TARGET may be a ***charset***.  In that case, use FONT-SPEC for all characters in the charset.
>   ...

But I cannot find any more information about what the "script name symbol" is?
I search via google to find some example that uses 'kan 'ascii 'kana. But I don't find any detail information about what it exactly is? Is there a way to list all the possible value?

BTW,
 Is there a way to list all the possible value of "charset" that is available to `set-fontset-font`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>M-:</kbd>`(char-table-extra-slot char-script-table 0)` gives

```
'(latin phonetic greek coptic cyrillic armenian hebrew arabic
  syriac nko thaana devanagari bengali gurmukhi gujarati oriya
  tamil telugu kannada malayalam sinhala thai lao tibetan burmese
  georgian hangul ethiopic cherokee canadian-aboriginal ogham runic
  khmer mongolian symbol braille han ideographic-description
  cjk-misc kana bopomofo kanbun yi cham tai-viet linear-b
  aegean-number ancient-greek-number ancient-symbol phaistos-disc
  lycian carian olt-italic ugaritic old-persian deseret shavian
  osmanya cypriot-syllabary phoenician lydian kharoshthi cuneiform
  cuneiform-numbers-and-punctuation byzantine-musical-symbol
  musical-symbol ancient-greek-musical-notation
  tai-xuan-jing-symbol counting-rod-numeral mathematical
  mahjong-tile domino-tile)
```

For character sets, try <kbd>M-x</kbd>`list-character-sets`.

Comment: That's Cool! And I have to said "HOW YOU KNOW THAT!" :D

Answer (score 5):

A "script name symbol" is a means to associate a lisp symbol with a particular charset, a set of charsets, or a range of characters. So, for example, if you look at the value of the variable "charset-script-alist", you will see an Alist of charsets vs the corresponding most appropriate script name symbols. If you look at the value of the variable "script-representative-chars", you will see an Alist of script name symbols vs the representative characters. The variable "char-script-table" shows the full mapping of characters to script name symbols (as specified by "script-representative-chars"). I don't know of any "definitive" list of script names (for example, "ascii" is a script name as well but isn't contained in these 2 variables); however, the values that are contained in the variables "charset-script-alist" and  "char-script-table"  are probably most of them.

To get a list of all the possible values of "charset" that is available to set-fontset-font, use the "list-character-sets" function. You can also use the "list-charset-chars" function to see the list of characters contained in a specific charset.

Comment: You answer is also great! Thanks for the detail explanation.